# Pivoting issue in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having some pivoting issue with a table. Could you someone please give some suggestion in this case?

My table looks like below:

```
 AgeRange       Male    Female
  21-30         15
  21-30                  11
  31-40         25
  41-50         18
  41-50                  22
  51-60         32
```

I want to look it like below by removing the duplicate rows in the age range,

```
 AgeRange       Male    Female
 21-30           15       11
 31-40           25
 41-50           18       22
 51-60           32
```

I used below,

```
 PIVOT (
 SUM (AgeRange) 
 FOR [AgeRange] IN ([MALE], [FEMALE])
 )
 AS AGE
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your data is already in the columns `Male` and `Female`, so if you want to get the sum of those columns by the age range, just use aggregation with a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT AgeRange,
  sum(Male) as Male,
  sum(Female) as Female
FROM <yourtable>
GROUP BY AgeRange
```

`PIVOT` is used to convert rows of data into columns but it appears you already have columns.

Answer (score 0):

**
SELECT age_range,Max(male),Max(female) FROM age_range GROUP   BY age_range ORDER BY age_range;
**